# I havent .bashrc file in my home folder

Tags: bash, debian

I added a new user, and logged in as it, but in home folder of my user didn't contain a `.bashrc` file.   why didn't this file get created?  Note that a `.bash_history` file did get created.

Comment: In addition to an answer: it's `~/.bashrc`, not `./bashrc`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either You created user by using some simple command that does not copy the skeleton for user directory

Or the skeleton directory in /etc/skel does not contain the .bashrc file

Answer (score 6):

This is not a problem. You can create the file if you need to customize your settings.